# How to get audio clip to play entirely before disconnecting

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have the bot joining and playing the audio but it doesn't seem to be consistent all the time. Sometimes it joins and plays starting halfway through. I'm assuming this has to do with the nature of async. Is there a way to ensure that the bot joins plays the audio then leaves in that order? My code is below

```
@bot.command(name='play_audio')
async def play_audio(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author == client.user:
        return

    voice = await join(ctx)
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/audio.mp3"))
    await leave(ctx)


@bot.command(name='j')
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author == client.user:
        return

    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        print(f"The bot has connected to {channel}\n")

    return voice


@bot.command(name='l')
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author == client.user:
        return

    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
        print(f"The bot has left {channel}\n")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are executing `leave()` before the playing is completed.

You can check [is_playing()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.is_playing) to wait for the mp3 to complete.

Also, using [asyncio.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping) to chill the while loop.

Try adding the following `while` before you leave:

```py
@bot.command(name='play_audio')
async def play_audio(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author == client.user:
        return

    voice = await join(ctx)
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/audio.mp3"))
    while voice.is_playing():
        await sleep(1)
    await leave(ctx)
```

Comment: Ah well that's a simple solution that I didn't think of. Thanks